# Check If IsEmpty, then Insert formula into cell accordingly

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check whether a cell in another worksheet is empty and then insert a formula accordingly.

My attempt looks like:

```
Range("IN47").Select
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value) = True Then
    Range("IN47").Formula = "=Concatenate('Name 1'!B2; " @ "; 'Name 1'!C2)"
    End If
```

I get invalid character the error message.
If I directly paste the formula into the cell then it works as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The common 2 problems (can be found hundred times on SO) when writing formulas with VBA: a) You need to specify your formula in US-EN format which means that you need to use comma as parameter separator. b) If you want to put a quote into the formula, you need to double it so the VBA runtime knows that your string is not ending.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched maybe 10 websites and just couldn't find the answer. Now it finally works